# Anime like mechs. The protagonist is a girl

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots

It's an anime I think new. I remember very few things. I remember that in one part there were many robots in a place like a prison where they were in poor condition and what kind of aliens or superior beings controlled them

Comment: This question is very terse and could be much improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Srry i have a really bad memory and i dont remember much. above i speack spanish and my english is bad  sorry

Comment: If you've found the answer, you should post it as an answer, rather then editing it into the question.

Comment: So it looks like the answer is [Deca-Dence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deca-Dence)? Or TS did not decide yet?

Comment: Its deca dence :D

Comment: @Luckas: Should you return, you can write up your own answer, or accept mine by clicking on the check mark by the voting button as per the [tour] (you can accept yours as well in the same way of clicking the checkmark).

Answer (score 4):

The querent attempted to edit an answer into their question, that they had found it was *[Deca-Dence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deca-Dence)*.

> In the latter part of the 2400s, air pollution reached lethal levels. As humanity hurtled toward extinction, they were also threatened by the emergence of life forms known as Gadoll causing the destruction of 90% of the world's population. Large corporations developed cyborgs to carry out human functions, but the cyborgs eventually began to outnumber humans and the Solid Quake corporation acquired rights to manage humanity. The company created a giant dome on the Eurasian continent in which they installed a colossal entertainment facility called Deca-dence, with its own independent all-governing system to make all decisions. The cyborg citizens could then safely experience adventure as human avatars at Deca-dence without the risk of real injury.
>
> In the fortress city of Deca-dence, the lowly Tanker girl, Natsume, dreams of becoming a Gear warrior following her father's death during a Gadoll attack. She is assigned to a maintenance team led by Kaburagi whom she discovers is more than he appears. Kaburagi has a secret role in eliminating "bugs", humans who threaten Solid Quake's operations. When Kaburagi discovers that Natsume is listed as dead in the company database, he decides to keep her under observation and offers to train her to fight.

The primary protagonist is Natsume.

> A teenage Tanker girl who lost her father and her right arm due to a Gadoll attack when she was a child. She has a prosthetic right arm and dreams of joining the Power and fight the Gadoll as a warrior, but after graduating from the Tanker Orphanage, she ends up working under Kaburagi as a maintenance worker.

The "robot prison" is Episode 6, ["Radiator"](https://deca-dence.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_6):

> The cyborg Kaburagi is sent to a bug correctional facility instead of being scrapped for insubordination as it appears that someone intervened in his behalf. He and the other bugs find themselves tasked with chopping up rock-hard Gadoll feces for reprocessing in to energy for Deca-dence. The job is unpleasant and dangerous, and the bug Sarkozy explains that no-one has ever left and escape is impossible. However, it is possible to illegally log into the Deca-dence system and he introduces Kaburagi to Donatello, leader of a tough band of bugs who has access. Donatello criticizes Kaburagi for not sticking to his principles in the past and becoming an armor repairer. He challenges Kaburagi to a Death Dive match above the rotating Gadoll feces crushers for a chance to contact Natsume through the Deca-dence link. As Kaburagi is about to win to match, Donatello takes both of them into the cesspit far below. However, Kaburagi uses his rocket backpack to fly them both back to the top. With Kaburagi having proved his resolve, Donatello authorizes the bug Jill to take Kaburagi to the Deca-dence link although he cannot use his former identity to connect. Meanwhile, at the Gadoll Factory Cell Production Room, newly produces Gadoll are being prepared to be released into the field.

### Trailer

Answer (score 1):

Could this be Neill Blomkamp's *Adam*? Not an anime, but heavy on the CGI.

Comment: No D: the animation is more like made in abyss its like tath